# How to reduce tabs bar size?

Tags: video, application-development, hardware

Its too large and annoying, I tried gnome-tweaks but no options found.
[image: Photo]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do to increase the efficiency of use of your screen real estate. Head to "Customize" ("hamburger" menu ☰ in the top right, then "Customize...")

1. Increase the density: on the bottom line, find the "Density" button. Set that to "Compact". That will render the UI elements of Firefox, among other the tabs, with minimum padding.
2. In the same area, unchecking the checkbox "Title bar" to remove the Firefox title bar.